# Remove all CDATA nodes and replace with encoded text

Tags: c#, xml, cdata, url-encoding

So, I've got a massive XML file and I want to remove all CDATA sections and replace the CDATA node contents with safe, html encoded text nodes.

Just stripping out the CDATA with a regex will of course break the parsing. Is there a LINQ or XmlDocument or XmlTextWriter technique to swap out the CDATA with encoded text?

I'm not too concerned with the final encoding quite yet, just how to replace the sections with the encoding of my choice.

Original Example

```
  ---
  <COLLECTION type="presentation" autoplay="false">
    <TITLE><![CDATA[Rights & Responsibilities]]></TITLE>
    <ITEM id="2802725d-dbac-e011-bcd6-005056af18ff" presenterGender="male">
      <TITLE><![CDATA[Watch the demo]]></TITLE>
      <LINK><![CDATA[_assets/2302725d-dbac-e011-bcd6-005056af18ff/presentation/presentation-00000000.mp4]]></LINK>
    </ITEM>
  </COLLECTION>
  ---
```

Sould Become

```
          <COLLECTION type="presentation" autoplay="false">
            <TITLE>Rights &amp; Responsibilities</TITLE>
            <ITEM id="2802725d-dbac-e011-bcd6-005056af18ff" presenterGender="male">
              <TITLE>Watch the demo</TITLE>
              <LINK>_assets/2302725d-dbac-e011-bcd6-005056af18ff/presentation/presentation-00000000.mp4</LINK>
            </ITEM>
          </COLLECTION>
```

I guess the ultimate goal is to move to JSON. I've tried this

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Server.MapPath( @"~/somefile.xml"));
            string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

But I end up with ugly nodes, i.e. "#cdata-section" keys. It would take WAAAAY to many hours to have the front end re-developed to accept this.

```
"COLLECTION":[{"@type":"whitepaper","TITLE":{"#cdata-section":"SUPPORTING DOCUMENTS"}},{"@type":"presentation","@autoplay":"false","TITLE":{"#cdata-section":"Demo Presentation"},"ITEM":{"@id":"2802725d-dbac-e011-bcd6-005056af18ff","@presenterGender":"male","TITLE":{"#cdata-section":"Watch the demo"},"LINK":{"#cdata-section":"_assets/2302725d-dbac-e011-bcd6-005056af18ff/presentation/presentation-00000000.mp4"}
```

Comment: `&` should become `&amp;` (HTML encoding), not `%26` (URL encoding). `/` does not need to be escaped in HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Process the XML with a XSLT that just copies input to output - C# code:

```
  XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
  transform.Load(@"c:\temp\id.xslt");
  transform.Transform(@"c:\temp\cdata.xml", @"c:\temp\clean.xml");
```

**id.xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you sure this has to work? There is nothing in the XSLT saying that CData nodes should be converted to normal text nodes. And just because it works for you doesn't mean it will work always work.

Comment: OK, not only did it produce valid encoded XML for a 1 MB balls-to-the-wall insane XML file, it fit right in with our XML->JSON methodology and gave clean results. darn'd tootin'.

Comment: The XSLT 2.0 spec is prescriptive on this: you only get CDATA in the serialized output if you ask for it. But the chances are an XSLT 1.0 processor will do the same. Note that the transformation here is unnecessarily complex: a simple `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` will suffice.

Comment: Nice. I still have a lot to learn about XSLT. this is the first time I've actually used one, be it simple, in a real scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Using LINQ to XML, you can do it like this:

```
XDocument doc = …;

var cDataNodes = doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XCData>().ToArray();

foreach (var cDataNode in cDataNodes)
    cDataNode.ReplaceWith(new XText(cDataNode));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can load the xml into a `XmlDocument` class. Then recursively process each `XmlNode` and look for `XmlCDataSection` node. This `XmlCDataSection` node should be replaced with`XmlTextNode` with same value.